# Excel VBA Scraping- HTML tables are not visible

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to get data from "https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/NSE-ABB/technicals/" using excel vba website scraping, eventhough I am geting response, but the body.innerHTML is not showing required table, but in chrome if I inspect the page, I am able to see the table with the name.

What is wrong with the code?

```
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    
    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))
    WriteTxtFile sResponse
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set tElementC = .getElementsByClassName("table-1i1M26QY- maTable-27Z4Dq6Y- tableWithAction-2OCRQQ8y-")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")
        
    End With
```

URL -->  https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/NSE-ABB/technicals/
classname to access = "table-1i1M26QY- maTable-27Z4Dq6Y- tableWithAction-2OCRQQ8y-"

Comment: MSXML just gets the source of the page - it does not run any scripts etc or download any other resources which might be required to build the table after the initial load of the page.  If the table is built dynamically you will need to use browser automation to get to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The webpage source HTML by the link provided https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/NSE-ABB/technicals/ doesn't contain the necessary data, it uses AJAX. The website has a sorta API available. The response is returned in JSON format. So you need to make some reverse engineering work first to find out how does the website works. In a browser, e. g. Chrome, press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open DevTools, navigate to the webpage, go to Network tab, set the filter to XHR, it will look like as shown below:

[image: network tab]

Examine logged responses. One of them having the largest size actually contains all the necessary data:

[image: json response]

To make such XHR you need to keep the entire payload structure also, and add the relevant headers:

[image: headers and form data]

In Form Data section there are a lot of quote field titles that located within the array, so you may choose which actually you need. You may find more available titles, click on Initiator link (first screenshot above), you will see JS code which initiated that XHR. Click Pretty print <kbd>{}</kbd> at the bottom to make the code readable. Type any title you already pulled out from Form Data in the search box, e. g. `Recommend.Other`, and find others next to it in the code:

[image: quote field titles]

Here is VBA example showing how such scraping could be done. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim aQuoteFieldTitles()
    Dim aQuoteFieldData()
    Dim sPayload As String
    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON
    Dim sState As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' Put the necessary field titles into array
    aQuoteFieldTitles = Array( _
        "name", "description", "country", "type", "after_tax_margin", "average_volume", "average_volume_30d_calc", "average_volume_60d_calc", "average_volume_90d_calc", "basic_eps_net_income", "beta_1_year", "beta_3_year", "beta_5_year", "current_ratio", "debt_to_assets", "debt_to_equity", "dividends_paid", "dividends_per_share_fq", _
        "dividends_yield", "dps_common_stock_prim_issue_fy", "earnings_per_share_basic_ttm", "earnings_per_share_diluted_ttm", "earnings_per_share_forecast_next_fq", "earnings_per_share_fq", "earnings_release_date", "earnings_release_next_date", "ebitda", "enterprise_value_ebitda_ttm", "enterprise_value_fq", "exchange", "expected_annual_dividends", _
        "gross_margin", "gross_profit", "gross_profit_fq", "industry", "last_annual_eps", "last_annual_revenue", "long_term_capital", "market_cap_basic", "market_cap_calc", "net_debt", "net_income", "number_of_employees", "number_of_shareholders", "operating_margin", _
        "pre_tax_margin", "preferred_dividends", "price_52_week_high", "price_52_week_low", "price_book_ratio", "price_earnings_ttm", "price_revenue_ttm", "price_sales_ratio", "quick_ratio", "return_of_invested_capital_percent_ttm", "return_on_assets", "return_on_equity", "return_on_invested_capital", "revenue_per_employee", "sector", _
        "eps_surprise_fq", "eps_surprise_percent_fq", "total_assets", "total_capital", "total_current_assets", "total_debt", "total_revenue", "total_shares_outstanding_fundamental", "volume", "relative_volume", "pre_change", "post_change", "close", "open", "high", "low", "gap", "price_earnings_to_growth_ttm", "price_sales", "price_book_fq", _
        "price_free_cash_flow_ttm", "float_shares_outstanding", "total_shares_outstanding", "change_from_open", "change_from_open_abs", "Perf.W", "Perf.1M", "Perf.3M", "Perf.6M", "Perf.Y", "Perf.YTD", "Volatility.W", "Volatility.M", "Volatility.D", "RSI", "RSI7", "ADX", "ADX+DI", "ADX-DI", "ATR", "Mom", "High.All", "Low.All", "High.6M", "Low.6M", _
        "High.3M", "Low.3M", "High.1M", "Low.1M", "EMA5", "EMA10", "EMA20", "EMA30", "EMA50", "EMA100", "EMA200", "SMA5", "SMA10", "SMA20", "SMA30", "SMA50", "SMA100", "SMA200", "Stoch.K", "Stoch.D", "MACD.macd", "MACD.signal", "Aroon.Up", "Aroon.Down", "BB.upper", "BB.lower", "goodwill", "debt_to_equity_fq", "CCI20", "DonchCh20.Upper", _
        "DonchCh20.Lower", "HullMA9", "AO", "Pivot.M.Classic.S3", "Pivot.M.Classic.S2", "Pivot.M.Classic.S1", "Pivot.M.Classic.Middle", "Pivot.M.Classic.R1", "Pivot.M.Classic.R2", "Pivot.M.Classic.R3", "Pivot.M.Fibonacci.S3", "Pivot.M.Fibonacci.S2", "Pivot.M.Fibonacci.S1", "Pivot.M.Fibonacci.Middle", "Pivot.M.Fibonacci.R1", _
        "Pivot.M.Fibonacci.R2", "Pivot.M.Fibonacci.R3", "Pivot.M.Camarilla.S3", "Pivot.M.Camarilla.S2", "Pivot.M.Camarilla.S1", "Pivot.M.Camarilla.Middle", "Pivot.M.Camarilla.R1", "Pivot.M.Camarilla.R2", "Pivot.M.Camarilla.R3", "Pivot.M.Woodie.S3", "Pivot.M.Woodie.S2", "Pivot.M.Woodie.S1", "Pivot.M.Woodie.Middle", "Pivot.M.Woodie.R1", _
        "Pivot.M.Woodie.R2", "Pivot.M.Woodie.R3", "Pivot.M.Demark.S1", "Pivot.M.Demark.Middle", "Pivot.M.Demark.R1", "KltChnl.upper", "KltChnl.lower", "P.SAR", "Value.Traded", "MoneyFlow", "ChaikinMoneyFlow", "Recommend.All", "Recommend.MA", "Recommend.Other", "Stoch.RSI.K", "Stoch.RSI.D", "W.R", "ROC", "BBPower", "UO", "Ichimoku.CLine", _
        "Ichimoku.BLine", "Ichimoku.Lead1", "Ichimoku.Lead2", "VWMA", "ADR", "RSI[1]", "Stoch.K[1]", "Stoch.D[1]", "CCI20[1]", "ADX-DI[1]", "AO[1]", "Mom[1]", "Rec.Stoch.RSI", "Rec.WR", "Rec.BBPower", "Rec.UO", "Rec.Ichimoku", "Rec.VWMA", "Rec.HullMA9" _
    )

    ' Field titles exactly as in the table MOVING AVERAGES
    ' aQuoteFieldTitles = Array("EMA5", "SMA5", "EMA10", "SMA10", "EMA20", "SMA20", "EMA30", "SMA30", "EMA50", "SMA50", "EMA100", "SMA100", "EMA200", "SMA200", "Ichimoku.BLine", "VWMA", "HullMA9")

    ' Compose payload
    sPayload = "{""symbols"":{""tickers"":[""NSE:ABB""],""query"":{""types"":[]}},""columns"":" & JSON.Serialize(aQuoteFieldTitles) & "}"
    ' Retrieve JSON response
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "https://scanner.tradingview.com/india/scan", True
        .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .setRequestHeader "user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "content-length", Len(sPayload)
        .send (sPayload)
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        sJSONString = .responseText
    End With
    ' Parse JSON response
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    ' Check response validity
    Select Case True
        Case sState <> "Object"
            MsgBox "Invalid JSON response"
        Case IsNull(vJSON("data"))
            MsgBox vJSON("error")
        Case Else
            ' Output data to worksheet #1
            aQuoteFieldData = vJSON("data")(0)("d")
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                .Cells.Delete
                .Cells.WrapText = False
                For i = 0 To UBound(aQuoteFieldTitles)
                    .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = aQuoteFieldTitles(i)
                    .Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = aQuoteFieldData(i)
                Next
                .Columns.AutoFit
            End With
            MsgBox "Completed"
    End Select

End Sub
```

The output for me is as follows:

[image: output]

BTW, the similar approach applied [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20json.bas).

Comment: how did I miss that?! +

Comment: Just like to know, which approach is faster QHarr's or omegastripes, cause I need to fetch for 3k stocks.

Comment: Hi, I've downloaded JSON.bas from https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser. but afte i imported the .bas file, I am unable to run your vba code. do I need to make any change after importing the .bas file?

Comment: Also, I am using MSExcel 2010 professional plus, will it support the above .bas.. please reply

Comment: @Kiran JSON.bas is supported by all MS Excel and Windows versions. Why are you unable to run the code? Any error messages?

Comment: Yes, compile error inside the imported module, after I've imported the .bas, its coming as module1 and everything is  errored inside in red (getting expected line number or statement or end of statement)... is the imported .bas in html format?

Comment: Make sure you are downloading and importing as shown on the screenshots by the links: [download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3epR.png) and [import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya5i4.png).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, javascript has to run on the page to update the required content. There doesn't appear to be an API freely available. You can use a browser. You need to go VBE > Tools > References > add a reference to Microsoft Internet Controls.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer, ws As Worksheet, hTable As Object, tRow As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long, headers()
    headers = Array("name", "value", "action")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"): Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/NSE-ABB/technicals/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set hTable = IE.document.querySelector("table + .tableWithAction-2OCRQQ8y-")
        ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        For Each tRow In hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            r = r + 1: c = 1
            For Each td In tRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                ws.Cells(r, c).Value = td.innerText
                c = c + 1
            Next td
        Next tRow
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```